# LNK2019 and LNK1120

Tags: c++

I am currently facing a problem which is as the error below

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup   MSVCRTD.lib assignment
```

I am trying to redo the program, I have follow the step to do as same as article post by any user. I try to change the character set to not set, still no function available. I try to change from console to win turn out _winmain@16 error, and I change back _main error
I ald recreate the whole solution file i didnt recreate the coding or .CPP and .H file in my C++ programming,

How do I solve it, I already research for 3 - 4 days, but I still unable to get the answer that I have expect. Hopefully this may help me to complete the program. Thank you and your help much appreciated.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LRcoKAkg8mI

Comment: ¤ Add a standard `int main() { ... }` C++ startup function. If necessary, in the linker settings change the entry point to `mainCRTStartup` (which calls `main`). Don't use the Microsoft `T` stuff, it's only for compatibility with Windows 9x. Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 0):

You've probably got some incompatible settings in your solution. In Visual Studio 2010, Create a new project, and select Win32 Console Application from the templates list. Click Next on the Wizard page, and select Console Application, and Empty Project, then Finish. Create a new .cpp file and put this code into it

```
int main ()
{
}
```

This should compile and link.

Answer (score 0):

if it is an windows program：
1.menu-Project->Properties, to open this "Property Pages" window 
2.then choose Configuration Properties->C/C++->Preprocessor,and delete "_CONSOLE" in Preprocessor Definitions , add "_WINDOWS".
3.return the first step:Configuration Properties->Linker->System,change it to Windows(/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS) in SubSystem

if it it a console program：
1.menu--> Project->Properties, pop out the "Property Pages" window
2.then choose Configuration Properties->C/C++->Preprocessor,and delete "_WINDOWS" int Preprocessor Definitions add  "_CONSOLE".
3.return the first step：Configuration Properties->Linker->System,change it to CONSOLE(/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE) in SubSystem

Answer (score -1):

Do you have a main function in your program? Because the windows runtime library (The  MSVCRTD.lib you mentioned) will call your main function as the entry point. If you don't have one, there is a link error.

WinMan is the entry point for the win32 program.

Comment: -1 "WinMan is the entry point for the win32 program" ← is incorrect. If you are talking about the machine code level entry point, the one specified by the linker's `/ENTRY` option, then that is a function of undocumented signature, but `void f()` works well. If you are talking about the C or C++ startup function, then the ISO standards for the languages require that to be `main`.